# Load files from cache when offline

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, pwabuilder

I'm trying to make a webpage available offline with pwabuilder.
The service worker is running and files are cached as expected, but when I switch to offline then the browser doesn't load the files from the cache ?
What I am missing ?
I used pwabuilder.com to generate the service worker files.
Here is my exemple : https://www.360images.fr/vrcache/

any clue would be much appreciate !!!

Comment: I see there's an `expires` response header for `/vrcache/` that is set to the current date/time, so it's expiring from the cache immediately. That appears to be the only thing that is unable to load. Maybe you should make that cachable.

Comment: Thanx @Jacob , I forgot to add /* to the cache array...

Answer (score 0):

Glad this has been solved :) And glad you're using pwabuilder for great VR content ;)

David